# Docker - install stuff in Dockerfile or external shell script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I figure there are two ways to install some dependency in Dockerfile:

1) in Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum install xxx
```

2) put "yum install xxx" in a script install.sh and in Dockerfile

```
RUN ./install.sh
```

Both seems to be working, just wandering is any one better than the other?

Comment: It really doesn’t matter.  The shell script might be easier to test outside of Docker; the inlined form might be easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nearly no difference for your afforded options. If you insist, I can tell you some little difference:

**1. The output of two images have different number of layers & a little size difference:**

A simple example as next:

#### Option 1:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install -y net-tools
```

**Build command:**

```
$ docker build -t trial:1 . --no-cache
```

#### Option 2:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM centos:7
ADD install.sh .
RUN ./install.sh
```

**install.sh:**

```
yum install -y net-tools
```

**Build command:**

```
$ docker build -t trial:2 . --no-cache
```

#### Compare:

```
$ docker history trial:1
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
f86f153f9d95        12 minutes ago      |0 /bin/sh -c yum install -y net-tools          105MB
9f38484d220f        3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.label-schema.sc…   0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:074f2c974463ab38c…   202MB

$ docker history trial:2
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
775be0061903        10 minutes ago      |0 /bin/sh -c ./install.sh                      105MB
b7ca1d2a7e8b        10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:6f96562be8deac728…   25B
9f38484d220f        3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.label-schema.sc…   0B
<missing>           3 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:074f2c974463ab38c…   202MB
```

From above, you can see if you use `./install.sh`, you will have to have a `ADD` instruction in `Dockerfile`. Compared to the option 1, it will increase a image layer about `20B` for your finally generated image.

**2. Maximum image layer limit:**

See [this discussion](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/8230#issuecomment-468630187), the maximum of docker image layers is 127, so if you in a special situation which base image or your image uses too many layers already, it maybe helpful.

**3. Efficiency of copy files from host to container:**

`ADD` need to copy file from docker host to container. Internally, `docker build` will create a tar file of the context directory, sending it to the docker daemon and unpack it. So the question will be why we need this if we could do it directly in `Dockerfile`?

**But do you really care the `20B`, one more layer & a little speed of COPY? I guess unless in some very bare situations, there is no difference for the 2 options.**

**However, seems `put package install directly in Dockerfile` is most people's choice, because folks may ask why I should put effort to maintain a `install.sh` if it did not bring any benefit to me.**

Comment: Thanks for all the insights! I would argue the install.sh script is much more portable and reusable, especially if I already have such a working script from non-docker environment?

Comment: Yes, if you have definite reason as you said, then you can use it as this do not cause big difference compare to write it in dockerfile for most of situations.

Answer (score 0):

`Docker` will create an image for each `Instruction` on your `Dockerfile` but if there was an image created with that `Instruction` already, it will use that image instead.

So when you have multiple `Instructions` on your `Dockerfile` to create your image, it's important to organize your `Instructions` in a way that it reduces the number of intermediate images.

So i think, if you put all your `Instructions` in one single file you may have less intermediate images. But also note that, any future changes in that file, will lead to creating a new intermediate image since there is nothing already created to be used which will make image creation time slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building docker images then use the below in the Dockerfile not the script to install the packages and its dependencies.

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install .. && \
    yum clean all

Use the custom shell script for running the application specific service(s) inside ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile.

Use the instructions for adding/installing packages in one RUN command to reduce the intermediate image layers.

Its good to use the shell script for installing the packages and its dependencies for non containers images/non docker images for automating the process for VM based apps.